# How do I compile abinit on a Cray XC30?

Tags: compilation, cross-compiling, hpc, cray

I am trying to compile the abinit code (http://www.abinit.org/) on a Cray XC30 machine (http://www.archer.ac.uk). Does anyone have a step-by-step procedure for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward. Instructions can be found at:

http://www.archer.ac.uk/documentation/software/abinit/compiling_7_phase2.php

and can be summarised as:

1. Switch to the Intel programming environment (GCC works too but produces slower code)

   ```
   module swap PrgEnv-cray PrgEnv-intel
   ```
2. Load the FFTW and NetCDF modules

   ```
   module load fftw
   module load cray-netcdf
   ```
3. Write a custom configuration file for autotools

   ```
   prefix="/path/to/your/install/directory"

   enable_mpi=yes
   enable_mpi_io="yes"
   enable_gw_dpc="yes"

   enable_64bit_flags="yes"
   enable_optim="aggressive"

   CC=cc
   CXX=CC

   FC=ftn
   FCFLAGS_EXTRA=""

   with_linalg_flavor="mkl"
   with_linalg_incs="-I$MKLROOT/include/intel64/lp64"
   with_linalg_libs="-L$MKLROOT/lib/intel64 -lmkl_lapack95_lp64 -lmkl_blas95_lp64 -lpthread -lm"

   with_fft_flavor=fftw3
   with_fft_incs="-I$FFTW_INC"
   with_fft_libs="-L$FFTW_DIR -lfftw3 -lfftw3f"

   with_trio_flavor="netcdf"
   ```
4. configure, make, make install